# Embed a local PDF in HTML page

Tags: html, pdf, embed, local, embedding

Situation:
Web application running on a remote server is displaying PDFs. PDF document is stored on client's PC (location is known).

Is there any way to embed that PDF into HTML page with local path?

p.s.:
So far i tried "object", "embed" and "iframe" and with no success.

I tried with file://, file:///, and without, URL with slashes and backslashes and nothing works. It works if opened directy in browser URL, just not by embedding

Comment: Is this web application serving the PDF from the client's PC to other PCs or is it simply to the single client?

Comment: Only the PC the PDF is stored on.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while ago, unfortunately there is no way of directly embedding a local file of any kind into a webpage.

Four solutions (neither that nice):

1. Build a signed (so it can access the client's computer) java app with an embedded PDF viewer using http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/ (or try to open the file using the default viewer). This applet could then be embedded in the webpage.
2. In HTML and a server side language, build an upload script to upload the PDF on the client's computer to a temp dir on your server, then display this PDF through another page.
3. Create an html page with the PDF embed code and the file:// at the beginning (giving an absolute path). Use headers to indicate this page is to be downloaded rather than viewed. The user would then open the file in their browser which would let the PDF be viewed (because the webpage is local, from the same IP address). This would work in IE, Opera but not Chrome, FF or Safari.
4. (What I would do) Make an application (.exe) in say Visual Studio C++. Embed the PDF viewer as activex, using the known url to the PDF (which could be stored in a static char array so your server side script could directly edit the exe to put the PDFs path in it). Then I would use the browser component to embed a browser next to the PDF on the screen - thus showing your online webpage next to the PDF, even if one can't be embedded in the other.

From Dev at http://yumyar.com